# Cover a div with 2 spans

Tags: html, css

I have this fragment of HTML:

```
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: silver">
    <span style="display: inline-block; background-color: red; width: 10px; height: 20px;"></span>
    <span style="display: inline-block; background-color: green; width: 10px; height: 20px; "></span>
</div>
```

My goal is to cover the outer `<div>` with two spans side-by-side, but instead, one span is on top of another span.

How to make it, so the red SPAN is on the left and the right SPAN is on the right? (note, I would like the solution to support more than 2 inner SPANs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you float the spans they will go side by side. An example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CzP94/).

```
   <div style=" width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: silver">
        <span style="display: inline-block; float:left;background-color: red; width: 10px; height: 20px;"></span>
        <span style="display: inline-block; float:left;background-color: green; width: 10px; height: 20px; "></span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the spans are `inline-block`, whitespace between them will appear as a space, and one will be pushed below because the width of the div does not account for that extra space. Try removing the whitespace between the spans with a comment (or putting them on the same line).

```
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: silver">
    <span style="..."></span><!--
    --><span style="..."></span>
</div>
```

I'd also recommend using stylesheets to style your elements and not use inline CSS. This will make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

William is correct in his assesment of your issue.  I've found that adding `font-size: 0` to the parent element, in your case the enclosing div, does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Like scrappedcola said it can be fixed by floating the inner elements but whenever you float something that should be clear so it can be like this:-

```
<div style=" width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: silver">
        <span style="display: inline-block; float:left;background-color: red; width: 10px; height: 20px;"></span>
        <span style="display: inline-block; float:left;background-color: green; width: 10px; height: 20px; "></span>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
```

here the extra div is a pseudo element to clear the floated elements

another method is using clearfix class on parent div

css for clearfi class is

```
.clearfix:after {clear:both;content:".";display:block;height:0;visibility:hidden;}
```

and your code should look like this:-

```
<div class="clearfix" style=" width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: silver">
            <span style="display: inline-block; float:left;background-color: red; width: 10px; height: 20px;"></span>
            <span style="display: inline-block; float:left;background-color: green; width: 10px; height: 20px; "></span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to give each span a class then you can use your style sheet/ style section to style them:

```
    <div style=" width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: silver">
      <span class="myspanclassone"></span>
      <span class="myspanclasstwo"></span>
    </div>
```